# How to insert a page in a DJVU file without quality loss?

Tags: djvu

So I have a DJVU file generated from a PDF (under Linux):

```
pdf2djvu --dpi=300 -o OUT.djvu IN.pdf
```

the PDF contained scanned notes.

In these days, I only got the DJVU file. The problem: I found a page missing (between 359 and 360 in the DJVU).

How can I insert a JPG file between the mentioned sites in the DJVU file? (I don't want degraded quality or much bigger DJVU file size, just the 180 KByte JPG in it)

solution could be OS independent. (windows, Linux)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can convert your DJVU file to .jpg and the .jpg to DJVU.

Comment: He doesn't want quality loss. JPEG is a lossy format. You can delete this answer to remove the downvote :)

Comment: If **jpg** format decrease your image quality then use **png** format type. Or while you convert your file make sure settings are set for high quality.